# Computed properties example in ember.js fails

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to learn emberjs and stumbled over an error in the example of the computed properties section (www.emberjs.com, 'Computed properties in action' example in the 'guides'section). It always shows the error "*Property 'fullName' of object [object Object] is not a function*" when I call `ironMan.fullName()` from the console of the browser - Why is that?

My code is:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0-rc.3/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.0.0-rc.6/ember.min.js"></script>
<script>
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  // these will be supplied by `create`
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

var ironMan = App.Person.create({
  firstName: "Tony",
  lastName:  "Stark"
});
</script>
```

Also in a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/UnevOVU/3/edit

Comment: Why do you have `.property('firstName', 'lastName')`? Without that it works fine.

Comment: @Dave this is called "computed property", one of the things that make Ember so awesome: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is telling you that `ironMan.fullName` is not a function and cannot be called with `()`. This is because `fullName` is a computed property object, not a function. You can access its value with the code shown directly below this code sample in the guide:

`ironMan.get('fullName') // "Tony Stark"`